# How to send multipart/form-data request from electron js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, electron, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send a file to my api using this code

```
async function send(url, file) {
    let formData = new FormData()
    let stream = fs.createReadStream(file.path)
    formData.append('file', stream, file.name)
    
    try {
        let response = await axios.post(url, formData, {
            headers: {
                ... formData.getHeaders(),
            Authentication: "Bearer ...",
        })
    } catch(err) {
        // Do something
    }
```

This code works when I run directly with node, for example, in the main process. But when I try to send this request from the electron browser, axios does not set the Content-Type header.
Is important to mention that I also tried using ajax and the XMLHttpRequest, but its allways the same.
This is what I get when sending it from electrin browser:
[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yB2J.png)